# how to validate a field that can be a digit or Url or a file to upload in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5.3

I have a field named `Photo` that coming from a form.

In the first step that field must be `required` to send and then **can be a digit number Or a Url Or a new uploaded photo file**.

I know how can I use [laravel validation rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#available-validation-rules) to check where it could be digit. like this:

```
'photo' => 'required|digit'
```

But I do not know how can I check if photo was not a **digit** is **url** or **uploaded file**.

Of course if I wrote like this :

```
'photo' => 'required|digit|url|file'
```

In this case laravel give me error if photo is a digit and is not a url.

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: I think form validation rules only pass if **all** the requirements are met. In your case, it is impossible. You'll probably need to write your own [Custom Validation Rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#custom-validation-rules).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

**App/Http/Requests/FormRequest.php**

```
public function rules()
{
   if(is_numeric($this->photo)) {
      $validation = 'digit';
   } else if (!filter_var($this->photo, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === false) {
      $validation = 'url';
   } else {
      $validation = 'file';
   }

 return [
      'photo' => 'required|' . $validation
    ];
 }
```

Note: Not tested, but it should give you the basic idea.